# django signals is not updating model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send an amount from a user to another user, i can't figure out what i am doing wrong.
Also, i just figured i didn't take into consideration the user's balance which makes the entire thing in my signals wrong. It seems i don't understand signals, i've gone through the documentation but i still can't figure it out.

signals.py

```
@receiver([post_save,post_delete], sender=wallet)
def post_save_sendcoins(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    wallet = instance.wallet
    
    sca=instance.sender
    waller_receiver=instance.receiver
    total = wallet.objects.filter(wallet=waller_receiver).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum']
    wallet.balance = total
    wallet.save(update_fields=['balance'])
    sca.save()
    waller_receiver.save()
```

models.py

```
class wallet(models.Model):
    owner=models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner', null=True)
    account_number = models.IntegerField() #deposit or withdrawal wallet
    balance = models.DecimalField(default=0.00,decimal_places=2,max_digits=15)
    virtualwallet = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this wallet should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.virtualwallet}-{self.owner}"
```

sendcoins model for sending an amount to a user's wallet

```
class sendcoin(models.Model):
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(wallet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    wallet = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='walll', null=True)
    
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='xender', null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.sender}"
```

Comment: Have you registered your signals inside AppConfig's ready function ?

Comment: Yes, I have added that.

Comment: Have you verified that `post_save_sendcoins` gets called? I don't think it is because you have an infinite recursive loop due to calling `wallet.save(update_fields=['balance'])`.

Comment: If you registered your app inside settings' INSTALLED_APPS just by its name then try to add `default_app_config = '<app_name>.apps.AppConfig'` in `__init__.py` of  your <app>
directory

Comment: @schillingt It doesn't.

Comment: Based on your signal code and how `instance` is used, it seems like it should be `sender=sendcoin` not `sender=wallet`. Also I would recommend sticking with convention and naming your classes as `UpperCamelCase` (i.e. `Wallet` and `SendCoin`) so that instances are distinct from classes. Once your signal handler does run it has an error right now because `wallet = instance.wallet` shadows the `wallet` class which is later used in `wallet.objects...`.